# How can I use aliases in the Go to Folder dialog?

Tags: macos, finder

Can I somewhere define aliases that I can use in the Go to Folder dialog?

More specifically, can I somehow setup Finder such that when I type `Pictures` it goes to the `~/Pictures` directory?

[image]

Comment: How about cmd+shift+H, followed by 'pic', followed by cmd+o or cmd+<down arrow>?  That for me takes just as much time if not less than cmd+shift+G, 'Pictures', <return>.

Comment: The `Pictures` folder is one example. I was hoping for a way to enhance the Go To functionality such that I could reach deeper folders easily as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no nice way to set up an alias in the Finder like you can in the Terminal, but you can set up text-expansion abbreviations in the Keyboard System Prefs' Text tab.

I prefer [Typinator](http://www.ergonis.com/products/typinator/) myself, as it is much more flexible and full-featured than the system prefs.

You could also roll-your-own utility using a script-runner utility and Applescript.